# Как корректно транскодировать 3gpp видео с помощью Intel INDE?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

При транскодировании видео в 3gpp формате в тот же формат, но в более низкое разрешение, вылетает

```
Exception 
java.lang.IllegalStateException 
android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method) 
at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:256) 
at     com.agent.mobile.TestAppActivity.initMediaCodec(TestAppActivity.java:234)
```

Пробовал менять выходной формат, а также

```
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, <bit rate>);
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, <sample rate>);
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
```

Видео было снято на штатную камеру.